# Xamarin Forms updating map pins when new pin added

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Map in Xamarin Forms that will show a collection of Pins stored in a SQLite database. Its quite simple, the map shows with the pins, there is an Add button at the top which presents with a textbox to give a new pin a Name. The Lat/Lng is populated automatically and when Save is pressed, the new pin should get added to the map.

When the map loads, the pins are not shown on the map. I have created a button to load the pins and they will show when that button is pressed.

A breakpoint in the ViewModel ExecuteLoadPinsCommand() shows that Pins does have pins inside it.

When I create a new pin, again the new pin doesn't show.

Here is the View. Note the toolbar button with the binding Pins.Count, thats the button I click to show the pins.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="WE.Views.MapPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WE.ViewModels"              
         Title="{Binding Title}">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MapPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddPinCommand}" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding Pins.Count}" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <maps:Map x:Name="myMap" ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}" IsShowingUser="True">
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pin Label="{Binding Name}" Position="{Binding Position}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:Map>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is the ViewModel.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    MapPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = _viewModel = new MapPageViewModel();

        _viewModel.LoadPinsCommand.Execute(this);
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        _viewModel.OnAppearing();

        await GetCurrentLocation();
    }

    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    async Task GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);

        if (location != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
            myMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), Distance.FromMeters(100)));
        }
    }

    private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePins();
    }

    void UpdatePins()
    {
        foreach (var pin in _viewModel.Pins)
        {
            Pin newPin = new Pin
            {
                Label = pin.Name,
                Position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(pin.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(pin.Longitude)),
                Type = PinType.Place
            };

            myMap.Pins.Add(newPin);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, here is the View Model

```
public class MapPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IMapService _mapService;

    public int PinCount { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MapPinModel> Pins { get; set; }

    public Command LoadPinsCommand { get; }

    public Command AddPinCommand { get; }

    public MapPageViewModel()
    {
        _mapService = new MapService();

        Title = "Map";

        Pins = new ObservableCollection<MapPinModel>();

        PinCount = 0;

        LoadPinsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadPinsCommand());

        AddPinCommand = new Command(OnAddPin);

        this.LoadPinsCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadPinsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Pins.Clear();

            Pins = await App.Database.GetPins();

            Debug.WriteLine("Pins in DB: " + Pins.Count.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public async void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    private async void OnAddPin(object obj)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddPinPage));
    }
}
```

**Add New Pin**

ViewModel

```
private readonly IMapService _mapService;

    private string userid;
    private string latitude;
    private string longitude;
    private DateTime dateadded = DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime datefound = DateTime.Now;
    private string name;

    public AddPinViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSave, ValidateSave);
        CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);
        this.PropertyChanged +=
            (_, __) => SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();

        _mapService = new MapService();
    }

    private bool ValidateSave()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name);
    }

    public string UserId
    {
        get => userid;
        set => SetProperty(ref userid, value);
    }

    public string Latitude
    {
        get => latitude;
        set => SetProperty(ref latitude, value);
    }

    public string Longitude
    {
        get => longitude;
        set => SetProperty(ref longitude, value);
    }

    public DateTime DateAdded
    {
        get => dateadded;
        set => SetProperty(ref dateadded, value);
    }

    public DateTime DateFound
    {
        get => datefound;
        set => SetProperty(ref datefound, value);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }

    public Command SaveCommand { get; }

    public Command CancelCommand { get; }

    private async void OnCancel()
    {
        // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }

    private async void OnSave()
    {
        var location = await GetCurrentLocation();
        var userid = await Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage.GetAsync("userId");

        MapPinModel pin = new MapPinModel()
        {
            Name = Name,
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            DateFound = DateTime.Now,
            Latitude = location.Latitude,
            Longitude = location.Longitude
        };

        await App.Database.AddPin(pin);

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }

    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    async Task<LatLngModel> GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        LatLngModel model = new LatLngModel();

        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);

        if (location != null)
        {
            model.Latitude = location.Latitude.ToString();
            model.Longitude = location.Longitude.ToString();
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: the setter for `Pins` needs to raise a `PropertyChanged` event, otherwise the UI is not aware that `Pins` has been updated

Comment: @Jason thats worked for the loading on the map thanks. How about when a new pin has been added to the database? Because its not updating the "parent" view model Pins? Ill update the post to include the Add Pin

Comment: the Add VM needs to tell the other VM a new Pin has been added.  There are a LOT of ways you could do this - the easiest might be to use `MessagingCenter`

Comment: you could also try loading all the pins in `OnAppearing` instead of in the constructor